# Merge pandas dataframe rows based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, merge

I want to merge or replace my data-1 of some rows based on my 'TIMESTEP' values in data-2.

I have tried both merge and replace options. On using replace, I am getting

```
"AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '_replace_columnwise'"
```

And on using merge methods I am not getting the desired results. I have tried this code:

```
x = data1.loc[data1['TIMESTEP'] == 500000]
y = data2.loc[df_nd_merged['TIMESTEP'] == 500000]
data1.replace(x, y, inplace = True)
```

My data1:

```
TIMESTEP    id  mass    y
2900    313 0.795699    -0.0149792
3000    462 0.782639    -0.0106693
3200    245 0.723805    -0.0167327
.....
.....
.....
TIMESTEP    id  mass    y
2487960 9999300 9934    0.802645    -0.0827138
2488086 9999800 3849    0.833692    -0.0247934
2488130 10000000 9532   0.767143    -0.0855542
```

My data2:

```
TIMESTEP    id  mass    y
500000  0   0   0
1000000 0   0   0
1500000 6272.0  0.877105    -0.0493408
1500000 7922.0  0.740305    -0.0443259
1500000 5699.0  0.772714    -0.0562289
2000000 0   0   0
2500000 0   0   0
3000000 0   0   0
3500000 0   0   0
4000000 0   0   0
4500000 0   0   0
5000000 0   0   0
5500000 0   0   0
6000000 1974.0  0.772978    -0.0270121
6500000 0   0   0
7000000 0   0   0
7500000 4870.0  0.92602 -0.0160799
8000000 6152.0  0.665494    -0.00542989
8500000 3300.0  0.67739 -0.0329551
9000000 30.0    0.798618    -0.0178684
9500000 0   0   0
```

Please help.

Comment: Please don’t post images of the data as we can’t test them. Instead, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), sharing a sample of the DataFrame(s) and the expected output within a code block along with your code. This allows us to easily reproduce your problem and help you. These should help:  [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, merge df with df2 on timestep and take the 'y' from df2

```
df[['TIMESTEP','id', 'mass']].merge(df2[['y']], 
                                    left_on=df['TIMESTEP'], 
                                    right_on=df2['TIMESTEP'],
                                    how='left').drop(columns='key_0')
```

DF

```
    TIMESTEP    id  mass    y
0   2900    313     0.795699    -0.014979
1   3000    462     0.782639    -0.010669
2   3200    245     0.723805    -0.016733
```

df2

```
    TIMESTEP    id  mass    y
0   5000    0.0     0.000000    0.000000
1   1000    0.0     0.000000    0.000000
2   3000    6272.0  0.877105    -0.049341
3   3200    7922.0  0.740305    -0.044326
4   1500000     5699.0  0.772714    -0.056229
```

MERGED

```
    TIMESTEP    id  mass    y
0   2900    313     0.795699    NaN
1   3000    462     0.782639    -0.049341
2   3200    245     0.723805    -0.044326
```

Answer (score 0):

[`pandas.DataFrame.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) works best for individual values and is not intended for row-wise replacements. It works like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create toy example
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df1.iat[0, 1] = 0

# replace zeros with -1
df1.replace(to_replace=0, value=-1)
```

This replaces all values of zero by minus one, without taking rows into account.

So you are correctly looking for [`pandas.DataFrame.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), which merges on one or multiple columns that exist in both dataframes (you can specify the columns explicitly if they do not have the same names by the keyword `left_on` and `right_on`).

```py
# create toy example
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2, 2), columns=['a', 'd'])
# force same values in a column
df1.loc[1, 'a'] = 0
df2.loc[0, 'a'] = 0

# slice 
lg1 = df1['a'] > 0.5
df1[lg1].merge(df2)
```

or you can simply work like you would slice a matrix, which might be a little more intuitive:

```py
# slice 
lg1 = df1['a'] > 0.5
df1[lg1] = df1[lg1] *-1
```

Note that the slices must be of the exact same size then.